# Why a class is written as rdfs:Class and a property is written as rdf:Property

Tags: rdf, rdfs

There are numerous examples of this.

Among the many, we can consider [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDF_Schema#Classes).

The above one says,

- **rdfs:Class** declares a resource as a class for other resources.
- **rdf:Property** – the class of properties.

Now, my question is, why is a class considered to be defined in RDF schema and 
property is considered to be simple RDF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is purely historic. The RDF model was defined *before* RDF Schema came along, and it already contained a vocabulary term for the notion of a property, so `rdf:Property` is part of the RDF namespace.

The notion of explicit classes was first introduced in RDF Schema, however, so it became `rdfs:Class`.

Comment: I never thought that the reason will be so trivial. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It is my custom to wait for two/three days before accepting an answer just to see if *a better one* pops up. I find it better to wait that period of time than to accept one and then accept another.

Comment: @Masroor Not a bad idea at all.  I may have misinterpreted your original comment.  'Thanks anyway' can sound sort of dismissive, like 'sure, but that's not what I actually want.'  I think you probably didn't mean it like that, though.